# Can Cassandra split a table?

Tags: cassandra

I am sorry if this is basic question; I'm still ramping up on Cassandra.

**Problem**:
Let's say I had a table. Each entry has a unique user ID as a "row key" and three columns (City, State, and Age)

I want to split this table into two tables with the same row keys but different columns. So there'd be one table called Location Table with two columns (City and State) and a second table called Age table with one column (Age).

**Question**: Is there a Cassandra command to split a table in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in command for that so you need to use some external tool, like:

- [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) with which you can unload data from table to disk, and then load data selectively - see the example 3 from [this blog post](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading) on how to use `-m` option.
- Spark with [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md) - read data, select only columns that you need & write into new table(s). Main advantage of Spark is that it can do everything in memory, you don't need much disk space. something like this (not tested, did use `spark-shell` with Scala. Follow documentation to set necessary connection properties):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

val df = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "tbl_name", "keyspace" -> "ks_name"))
  .load()
// write locations
df.select("rowid", "city", "state")
  .createCassandraTableEx("ks_name", "location_table", 
    partitionKeyColumns = Some(Seq("rowid"))
// write age
df.select("rowid", "age")
  .createCassandraTableEx("ks_name", "age_table", 
    partitionKeyColumns = Some(Seq("rowid"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra can't do that for itself - *you* have to do the work.

Question: Why are you splitting out such a "small" value into its *own* table?
There is a [small] storage and processing overhead in doing so, so I'm *guessing* you have some *other* reason (Data Security, perhaps?).

Also, do not store `Age`.
It changes - every single day - and making changes to every row in a table [every day] is an *expensive* operation, in terms of the database power needed to do it, the potential impact on your system *while* it's being done and to your Business [reputation] if you accidentally "miss" a day and everyone suddenly becomes a day "younger"!

Instead, store a fixed value like `Date of Birth` and *calculate* the Age, as and when you need it.

Comment: The example was intended to be for illustrative purposes only. The general reason I'm interested in splitting a table is to move some data to a non-Cassandra data source.